# custom comment_form fields not displaying

Tags: custom-field, comments, comment-form

My ideal comment form will have 3 fields- Name, Location, Comment.
I'm using the following bits of code-

comments.php

```
<?php comment_form(
    array(
        'fields' => apply_filters( 'comment_form_default_fields', $fields ),
        'comment_notes_after' => ' ',
        'title_reply' => 'Please feel free to share your home owning hopes, dreams, or concerns?',
        'logged_in_as' => '',
    )
); ?>
```

functions.php

```
<?php

function my_fields($fields) {
$fields['Name'] = '<p>Name</p>';
$fields['Location'] = '<p>Location</p>';
return $fields;
}
add_filter('comment_form_default_fields','my_fields');

?>
```

As you can see on the [live site](http://zoparealty.com/share/), that's not working. Any ideas why/how to remedy?

Answer (score 1):

I think you're a bit confused about how `comment_form` works.  So let's take a look (this is in `wp-includes/comment-template.php`):

```
<?php
function comment_form( $args = array(), $post_id = null ) {
    // snip snip 
    $fields =  array(
        'author' => '<p class="comment-form-author">' . '<label for="author">' . __( 'Name' ) . '</label> ' . ( $req ? '<span class="required">*</span>' : '' ) .
                    '<input id="author" name="author" type="text" value="' . esc_attr( $commenter['comment_author'] ) . '" size="30"' . $aria_req . ' /></p>',
        'email'  => '<p class="comment-form-email"><label for="email">' . __( 'Email' ) . '</label> ' . ( $req ? '<span class="required">*</span>' : '' ) .
                    '<input id="email" name="email" type="text" value="' . esc_attr(  $commenter['comment_author_email'] ) . '" size="30"' . $aria_req . ' /></p>',
        'url'    => '<p class="comment-form-url"><label for="url">' . __( 'Website' ) . '</label>' .
                    '<input id="url" name="url" type="text" value="' . esc_attr( $commenter['comment_author_url'] ) . '" size="30" /></p>',
    );

    $required_text = sprintf( ' ' . __('Required fields are marked %s'), '<span class="required">*</span>' );
    $defaults = array(
        'fields'               => apply_filters( 'comment_form_default_fields', $fields ),
        'comment_field'        => '<p class="comment-form-comment"><label for="comment">' . _x( 'Comment', 'noun' ) . '</label><textarea id="comment" name="comment" cols="45" rows="8" aria-required="true"></textarea></p>',
        'must_log_in'          => '<p class="must-log-in">' . sprintf( __( 'You must be <a href="%s">logged in</a> to post a comment.' ), wp_login_url( apply_filters( 'the_permalink', get_permalink( $post_id ) ) ) ) . '</p>',
        'logged_in_as'         => '<p class="logged-in-as">' . sprintf( __( 'Logged in as <a href="%1$s">%2$s</a>. <a href="%3$s" title="Log out of this account">Log out?</a>' ), admin_url( 'profile.php' ), $user_identity, wp_logout_url( apply_filters( 'the_permalink', get_permalink( $post_id ) ) ) ) . '</p>',
        'comment_notes_before' => '<p class="comment-notes">' . __( 'Your email address will not be published.' ) . ( $req ? $required_text : '' ) . '</p>',
        'comment_notes_after'  => '<p class="form-allowed-tags">' . sprintf( __( 'You may use these <abbr title="HyperText Markup Language">HTML</abbr> tags and attributes: %s' ), ' <code>' . allowed_tags() . '</code>' ) . '</p>',
        'id_form'              => 'commentform',
        'id_submit'            => 'submit',
        'title_reply'          => __( 'Leave a Reply' ),
        'title_reply_to'       => __( 'Leave a Reply to %s' ),
        'cancel_reply_link'    => __( 'Cancel reply' ),
        'label_submit'         => __( 'Post Comment' ),
    );

    $args = wp_parse_args( $args, apply_filters( 'comment_form_defaults', $defaults ) );

        // $args get used to fill out the fields here
}
```

You need only to override the arguments you want to change. If you want custom fields, simply pass in the fields -- no need to bother with hook into `comments_form_default_fields`.

Overly simplified example:

```
<?php comment_form(array(
    'fields'    => array(
        'author' => '<input type="text" name="author" />',
        'location' => '<input type="text" name="location" />',
    ),
));
```

WordPress will handle saving the author field, but you'll have some more work to do for getting location saved.  I wrote a [tutorial about this](http://pmg.co/adding-extra-fields-to-wordpress-comments).

Basically: hook into `comment_post`. Check `$_POST` for the field, save it:

```
<?php
add_action( 'comment_post', 'wpse69222_insert_comment', 10, 1 );
function wpse69222_insert_comment( $comment_id )
{
    // prolly should do more validation here?
    if( isset( $_POST['location'] ) )
        update_comment_meta( $comment_id, 'location', esc_attr( $_POST['location'] ) );
}
```

You might also want admin area fields and a way to edit that location from the admin, but that's another question.

Comment: thank you for you input(and the link to your tutorial).
i've made the changes per your comment, and not only are the custom fields still not showing, but I'm now receiving the following error from `wp_list_comments`

Warning: call_user_func() expects parameter 1 to be a valid callback, function 'my_custom_comments' not found or invalid function name in /home/content/56/9896856/html/wp-includes/comment-template.php on line 1336

Comment: That's a separate issue. You can pass a callback to display the comment in [`wp_list_comments`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_list_comments).  It means the function `my_custom_comments` doesn't exist.  So you can create it or remove the callback.  [Here's the custom callback](https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/blob/master/wp-content/themes/twentyeleven/functions.php#L517) in TwentyEleven for an example.

Comment: I think the parent had issue where the fields are not shown when you are logged in. This is intended behaviour, and instead one must print the fields in two actions: `comment_form_logged_in_after` and `comment_form_before_fields` if it's required to show the fields in logged in as well as logged out users.